# SQL or PLSQL to fetch procedure parameters and types

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is there any way to fetch parameters used by stored procedure (can by sample of `SQL` of `PL/SQL`)?

From view `USER_PROCEDURES` I can check only flags, existence and permission to execute but nothing about input parameters and their types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[dba][all][user]_arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1014.htm#i1573843) data dictionary view allows you to view arguments of stored procedures:

```
/* test procedure */
create or replace procedure P1(
   p_par1 in number, 
   p_var2 in number, 
   p_cursor out sys_refcursor
)
as
begin
  null;
end;


/* list all formal parameters of P1 stored procedure */
select argument_name
     , t.position
     , t.data_type
  from user_arguments t
 where object_name = 'P1'
```

Result:

```
Argument_Name Position  Data_Type 
---------------------------------
P_CURSOR      3         REF CURSOR 
P_VAR2        2         NUMBER 
P_PAR1        1         NUMBER
```